# Python: Is there a way to update the keys (columns) of a DictWriter before calling writerow()?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, instantiation

[csv.Dictwriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) is instantiated thus:

```
 class csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='raise', dialect='excel', *args, **kwds)
```

`fieldsnames` is a sequence of keys, or in my case, a dict.

Here's my question; after instantiating DictWriter with a certain dict, I wish to remove some of the keys (and by extension, values) of `fieldnames` before calling `writerow()`. For reasons I won't get into, I can only tell the code which keys to remove **after** `DictWriter` has been instantiated. Dict has just 3 methods:

```
writerheader
writerow
writerows
```

.. none of which are any help. Based on my testing, it seems that when `DictWriter` is instantiated, it sets the column names of the csv-to-be according to `fieldnames`. And any change made to `fieldnames` after instantiation has no effect on the column headers that will be generated. Because DictWriter defines the columns at instantiation, am I stuck with these? Or is there a way around this?

Comment: I think you can use csv.writer and loop through all rows to write so that you have full control over each row and its values before writing.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha But since each row must have the same keys (column names) as all the rest, how does having control over each row serve my purpose? I'm looking to get rid of the columns themselves, irrespective of the value of the column for any given row.

Comment: Could you please tell how have you structured the data to be iterated through? That means, how are rows to be written structured in your code. I am assuming it to be a list of dicts and posting an answer.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha I'm unable to edit my post. The data to be written to the CSV is structured very similarly to what you see here: https://gist.github.com/Pyderman/2263d6887b9963d3d1ca Between line 297 and 306, I'm looking to remove some columns, namely, those columns where I know the the value of they key matches a certain string. They are not columns created for fields in the email headers. Rather they are one which I have created before instantiating DictWriter at line 297.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a dict like -

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

then you can use csv.writer as follows:

```
f = open('abc.csv', 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f, dialect=csv.excel, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row in rows:
    csv_writer.writerow([row['b'], row['c'])  # Assuming we dont want keys 'a' and 'b' to be written
f.close()
```